# database error after Heroku deployment for django app

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, django-views, heroku-postgres

I made a simple API using the Django REST framework and consumed the API with ajax.

This is my first time using Heroku, after I deployed the project it tries to save the data to a relation called "api_task" which causes an error.

I have debug on True and this error shows when I try to add a new task to my todo app:

> relation "api_task" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "api_task"
> ("title", "completed") VALUES ('new t...

this is my model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

ajax call for creating and updating new tasks

```
    let method = 'POST';
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-create/';
    
    if (activeItem){
        method = 'PUT';
        url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-update/${activeItem.id}/`;
        activeItem = null;
    }

    const title = document.getElementById("title").value
    fetch(url, {
        method:method,
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-CSRFToken': csrfToken
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'title':title})
    })
    .then(response =>{
         buildList()
         document.getElementById('form').reset()
    })
```

the create view

```
@api_view (['GET','POST'])
def task_create(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        task_serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(task_serializer.data)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        if task_serializer.is_valid():
            task_serializer.save()
            return Response(task_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(task_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the serializer

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Provide the view that handle: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-create/`

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow I added them now, btw i did change the localhost url to the heroku url

Comment: you have applied database migrations on the server?

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow How do you do that, I just deployed it thought it would connect automatically

Comment: Connect to your server and manually run: ‘python manage.py makemigrations’ and ‘python manage.py migrate’

Comment: didnt work everything is migrated @RedWheelbarrow